# Replacing an element by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have html output in paging section like this;

```
<p>&nbsp;<strong class="active">1</strong>&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/project/report_nc/search_now/1">2</a>&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/project/report_nc/search_now/2">3</a>&nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/project/report_nc/search_now/1">Next »</a>&nbsp;</p>
```

Now i need to add attribute "onclick" using jquery. BUt unfortunately "onclick" attribute cannot be set with jquery. At the same time i came up with an idea : taking a single anchor tag (i.e. `<a href="http://localhost/project/report_nc/search_now/2"></a>`) and replace it by a new anchor tag (i.e. `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(2)"></a>`).

How would i do it with jquery? The idea is to post the form while clicking on the paging links.

**SOLVED !**

Thank you all for your kind responses......I guess there was a minor mistake in my code; as i was looking through the code posted by [umesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914184/umesh) i noticed "`onClick`"...yes i was using "`onclick`" instead of "`onClick`". Now it has worked in FF and hopefully it will work in IE too.

Comment: Onclick can be set with jQuery. Are you saying you don't want to do that or you don't know how? `$('a').click(function() { alert(); });`

Comment: yes but i wanted it to be set in the "onclick" attribute, so that it would look more fair and less javascript codes in the page as well.... thank you for the response !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of the anchor can be used to pass the value to function `myFunction`. If Anchor doesn't contain any value, don't do anything.

Working Test code as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Use Proper anchor selector on your page 
     $("a").each(function(){
       var no=$(this).html();
       if(!isNaN(parseInt(no))){
            $(this).attr("onClick","myFunction("+no+")");
            $(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0)");
      }
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>&nbsp;
    <strong class="active">1</strong>&
    nbsp;
    <a href="http://localhost/project/report_nc/search_now/1">2</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="http://localhost/project/report_nc/search_now/2">3</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="http://localhost/project/report_nc/search_now/1">Next »</a>&nbsp;
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) like so:

```
$('a').replaceWith('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction(2)" />');
```

Although I'd recommend looking into why it is that makes you can't set onclick attribute using jquery, if you would like to bind a click event, you can use .click()

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   myFunction(2);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in jquery

```
$('a').click(function(){
    myFunction($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well making the assumption that you would prefer to use a click handler rather than replace your entire anchor tag, take a look at this. The only thing you need to do is `return false` in the click event so that the default navigation doesn't occur.

http://jsfiddle.net/2GgK3/

```
//if any link is clicked
$('a').click( function() {
    var clickedLink = $(this).prop('href'); //get its href 
    console.log(clickedLink); //output to console
    return false; //prevent default navigation
});
```

You also CAN set attributes directly in jQuery. In jQuery 1.7+ use `prop`. Otherwise use `attr`.

```
$('element').prop('href', 'new href value');
```